# Visual Studio + localdb on windows 10

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

I just got a new machine and put windows 10 on it. I am a student so I have a dreamspark account and obviously want to download the latest version of VS which I think with dreamspark is 2015 Community. I want to create web sites with databases using local db then deploy them to Azure. Does 2015 Community come with everything I need to do that or do I also have to get SQL server 2014 and does it all work on Windows 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL server is included in VS 2015 and works Windows 10.